# Can i use empty() for a Undefined Variable?

Tags: php, variables, session, isset

index.php:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
}
###$_SESSION['user_id'] is = to $user['user_id'] that i get from database in a select query on login.php
```

As you can see above, i set the variable `$user_id` only when the user is loge in. I use `if(empty($user_id)){}` to make some conditons and it's working well, but i'm curious, because if the user is not logged in `$user_id` will be a Undefined Variable, i'm new to php, so i want to know if i'm doing it correctly.

On a page that the user should not view unless he is logged in i have added this code:

```
if(empty($user_id)) {
  $_SESSION['message'] = "You need to loge in to view this page";
  header("location: verify/error.php");
  exit;    
}
```

And to display some content related to the user i use this code:

```
if(!empty($user_id)){
   echo 'content related to the user, divs...etc';
}
```

I have two questions:

**1 - Am i doing it correctly?**

**2 - Should i change my code to:**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
}else{
  $user_id = '';
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can.From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php): _"A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or.."_. I personally would set an additional boolean flag like `isLoggedin` just for better readability

Comment: "correctly" is very subjective, but for all intents and purposes you should **always validate** the `$_SESSION`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_ENV`,  `$_FILES` and `$_SERVER` superglobals data. You should never assume it is going to be the expected data type and use `array_key_exists` or `isset` along with `filter_var` or type casting when applicable, to prevent your apps from being compromised. For example https://3v4l.org/WBIPe Keep in mind that array data is passed by-copy and not by-reference. So if `$_SESSION['xyz']` changes your assigned variable will not change.

Comment: @fyrye `array_key_exists` is a mysql function right? I'm not sure because i did not use it yet. On my whole project i used only PDO, there will not have a conflict?

Comment: @user236945896 [`array_key_exists`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) is a global function for all arrays

Comment: @fyrye I saw on the answear below that a ID can be forged, i actually had thought about this, but... `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['user_id']` the user id is on my table and i use POST method. I know that nothing can be 100% secure, but this condition is enough? `if (\array_key_exists('user_id', $_SESSION) && $user_id = \filter_var($_SESSION['user_id'], \FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {` If not, what do i need to do? PS: I'm worry about my database, because registred users will not have any private information on their profile, unless the e-mail and password.

Comment: The condition will ensure that the `$_SESSION['user_id']` that is assigned to the `$user_id` variable is an integer value. As opposed to something like `$_SESSION['user_id'] = '0 OR true'` or more malicious, which I advise you to protect against  While `empty` can validate that a variable has been defined, it does not determine the "intent" of the variable data, which is highly encouraged.  For example [`unserialize`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), take note of the red message at the top, now has `allowed_classes`, to prevent exploitation of the function

Comment: I should also mention that PHP uses [`serialize` and `unserialize` by default for handling session data](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler)....

Comment: @fyrye "or more malicious". What kind of malicious thing?

Comment: Well, in the event of not using prepared statements. `;DROP TABLE users` for example, but user data should NEVER be trusted, which encompasses all superglobals.

Comment: @fyrye I'm using prepared statements. If you said that, then i think that there's no much thing to worry about

Comment: It was a very well-known and simple example of one point of vulnerability. There are a great deal more to be wary of. My suggestion is simply to help you confirm to best practices and avoid your app becoming hacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Am I doing it correctly?**

First and foremost, my answer isn't going to describe the implementation of using `empty()` in your case against undefined variable warnings. This answer is to give you direction, and show you a bit of OOP for your case and why its efficient.

Take, as an example, page A doesn't require a user to be authenticated for read access but page B does.

Rather than re-writing this check, consistently throughout your application for page 'n', we can write a class structure that does it for you depending on the access scope.

Lets start of by making the application know when to disallow read access by creating an interface. This will eventually be used to extend the User authentication class whenever we want to revoke read access when a user is not logged in.

```
namespace Application\Auth;

interface MustBeLoggedIn
{
}
```

Next, we can go ahead and build the authentication class. This is what holds the directive of how, or what order, this class will execute its methods depending on its instance type.

```
namespace Application\Auth;

class Authenticable {

    protected $_user_id;
    private $_csrf = 'user_id';

    public function __construct()
    {
        # PHP 7+
        $this->_user_id = $_SESSION[$this->_csrf] ?? '';

        # PHP < 5.6
        # $this->user_id = isset($_SESSION[$this->_csrf]) ? $_SESSION[$this->csrf] : '';

        if($this instanceof MustBeLoggedIn)
            $this->mustBeLoggedIn();
    }

    private function mustBeLoggedIn()
    {
        if(!isset($this->_user_id))
            $this->authError();
    }

    protected function authError()
    {
        exit();
    }

    protected function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return isset($this->_user_id);
    }

}
```

Finally, we can build two User classes. The first class will revoke read access to any unauthorised users.

```
namespace Application\Auth;

class User extends Authenticable implements MustBeLoggedIn
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        if($this->isLoggedIn())
            echo $this->_user_id;
    }

    protected function authError()
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Oh snap! Looks like you need to be logged in to view this page.';
        header('Location: verify/error');
        exit();
    }
}
```

The second class will allow both Guests and authenticated users to have read access.

```
namespace Application;

class User extends Authenticable
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        if($this->isLoggedIn())
            echo $this->_user_id;

        if(!$this->isLoggedIn())
            echo 'Well, you can still view this page';
    }
}
```

Deploying a view is now easy. Without having to constantly re-declare whether the value exists, and decide what to do, you can instance whichever suits your scope.

If we want to give the user read access when he is logged in or logged out, we can use Application\User.

```
class MyView extends \Application\User {
    public function sayHi() {
        echo $this->isLoggedIn() ? "Hi, {$this->user_id}!" : "Hi, Guest!";
    }
}

(new MyView())->sayHi();
```

If we want to revoke read access to unauthorised users, we can use Application\Auth\User.

```
class MyView extends \Application\Auth\User {
    public function sayHi() {
        echo "Hi, {$this->user_id}!";
    }
}

(new MyView())->sayHi(); # Guests will be redirected to error/verify
```

I hope by showing you this, it might help you understand a bit more about PHP. Also, things to note is that you're likely vulnerable to [CSRF attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) because an ID (assuming representing an integer) is extremely easy to forge. Perhaps look at [using a JSON Web Token](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) and pass the user ID into it.

```
$_SESSION['csrf'] = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode(array('user_id' => 1), 'secret'); # An integer represented a base-64 encoding is going to stand out, perhaps store a generated unique token or something else in regards to identifying this user
$user = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode($_SESSION['csrf'], 'secret', array('HS256')); # $user['user_id'] would hold 1
```

Touching on fyrye's comment regarding exploitation within the usage of JWT, the biggest point to take away is HS256 security majority deriving from the secret. *What does that mean?* It means you are in control of how secure you make it. The method I use is to think of a secure password, but something to do with the JWT.

```
$secret = '_userAuthentication%App';
```

Then, to increase the security of this, I hash the password before I provide it to the HS256 for usage of encryption.

```
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

JWT::encode(array(
    'Data' => 'You want to secure from the user',
    'Integrity' => 'This STILL should not mean it is trusted data'
), password_hash($secret, PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

When decoding the JWT, it is also important to remember the basics - **never trust data**. We can make use of the `try catch finally` blocks, disregarding finally in this case, to ensure that we're getting the correct information back.

```
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

try {
    $csrf = JWT::decode($jwt, password_hash($secret, PASSWORD_BCRYPT), array('HS256'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Data was invalid - Potential forge ?
}
```

Final note, if you're using SSL - which these days is a requirement, then sign the JWT with RSA.

Comment: @user236945896 be warned the JWTs are [also exploitable](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/09/28/attacking-jwt-authentication/). and  it is advisable to not store user_ids to authenticate against in them.

Comment: @fyrye I updated my answer to provide that little extra regarding your comment, thanks :)

Comment: @Jaquarh your updated example will fail decoding, as `password_hash` uses a random salt, resulting in a unique value, each time it is called. See: https://3v4l.org/65Bk9  It is recommended instead to use versions for the signature, per instance. Meaning each JWT would have their own unique secret that can not be influenced, and if the version changes, the client JWT becomes invalid for only that instance and is not exploitable. https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/3.3/README.md and https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/

Comment: Also would like to suggest segregating terminology for CSRF and JWT. CSRF tokens are a means to prevent an external source from submitting data to your application without a valid token. The CSRF token should be unique per request. While the JWT acts more like a signature, such as "authorized device", and does not need to change per request. In general you would want to implement both CSRF tokens and JWT two-factor authentication.

Comment: Feel free to update, i mainly named it that since i was explaining how to prevent forging @fyrye

Answer (score 1):

To check if a variable has been set you should use `isset()` to test that. `empty()` will also return `true` if a false value is returned. From the doc page, the following values are considered false:

> "" (an empty string)
>
> 0 (0 as an integer)
>
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
>
> "0" (0 as a string)
>
> NULL
>
> FALSE
>
> array() (an empty array)

So if `$user_id` could have one of these values (maybe the integer 0) then you could get an unexpected result. If `$user_id` will never be one of these values, then you could check if it is set using `!empty()` without any issues.

Comment: "To check if a variable has been set you should use `isset()` to test that" It's a problem if i use `if(!empty())`?

Comment: I've update the answer, but you should be fine using `!empty()` unless you could have a valid `$user_id === 0` or something like that.